# require js в один файл

Tags: grunt, requirejs

В папке lib имеется файл main.js, который импортирует модуль:

```js
//    код основного файла

require.config({
    baseUrl: './../',
    paths: {
      module: './lib/module'
    }
});

require('module', (module) => {
  
    //...
  
  }
```

```js
// Код модуля

function f() {
  
  экспортируемая функция

}

define(() => {
       
       return f;
       
});
```

Как с помощью grunt создать один js файл, который можно прикрепить без каких-либо библиотек, который будет выполняться так же, как main.js выполнялся с requirejs?

Comment: любым сборщиком типа gulp, grunt, webessentials, сборщик в visual studio - вариантов куча

Comment: @Grundy можно поконкретнее, как это делать? Просто все эти инструменты, насколько я понял, выполняют очень много функций, а именно про сборку requirejs модулей я не нашел.

Comment: все зависит от конкретного инструмента. На данный момент вопрос _слишком_ широк.

Comment: @Grundy, было бы здорово разобрать шаги, как сделать эту задачу с самым простым из них

Comment: А какой из них по вашему самый простой? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, тот, в котором меньше вводить, и легче разобраться :D

Comment: Это полностью индивидуально, один одно, другим другое

Comment: @Grundy, я думаю, grunt вполне подойдет

Comment: Тогда отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы он отражал текущую цель

Comment: @Grundy, готово